# Protected methods on class inheritage

Tags: javascript

I am able to find much material on articles about private and protected variables in **javascript**. But what about methods?

May you give an example on how to properly extend the class interface with some protected method?

Comment: [all the information you want](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields), but note that there is no "protect", there's only "private" and "normal" visibility.

Comment: Thanks sir. I may come back to greet with some fruits from this interchange.

Comment: What do you mean by "*private and protected variables*"? What does that have to do with "*class inheritance*"?

Comment: JavaScript uses the same mechanism for data properties and methods. So both private properties and private methods are indicated by beginning them with `#`.

Comment: @Bergi I recommended you to read the first comment. It explains the relation.

Comment: @Barmar I am aware of private variables/methods. It seems, there is no protected method or variables on Javascript. Sad

Comment: They only recently added private.

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto No. The MDN page Mike linked talks about private class fields, which are *properties*, not variables, and it doesn't talk about "protected variables" at all. So again, what do you mean?

Comment: I see. Well, he explained already, there is no protected property or method in javascript. So, nevermind...